# Fetch usergroups structure from Alfresco using CMIS

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

Is it possible to retrieve the structure of usergroups from Alfresco using a CMIS session, and if so, how do I do it?

I use GXT (Java) and Apache's chemistry openCMIS API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible, if you'd searched the alfresco forums then you didn't had to ask the question ;).

[Here](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=45603) is a similar question and answer on the forum.

Comment: I noticed that said before, but found other sources saying it IS possible. Unfortunately, that wasn't backed up in any case, so I came here. Thanks for the answer.